# How to use markdown in middleman yaml locals

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml, middleman

I'm using Middleman localization to push a bunch of documentation from yaml to ruby file. The problem is, I don't know how to use markdown in yaml file and yield the markdown yaml to ruby file.

yaml data file:

```
features:
    title: "14 Chapters"
    text: "The book's main chapters take you through building a **social news site**."
    image: "files.svg"
    title1: "11 Sidebars"
    text1: "In between each chapter, sidebars explain a specific aspect of Meteor."
    image1: "files.svg"
```

locals.html.erb:

```
<div class="banner">
    <h2 class="s-heading"> 
          <%= I18n.t("features.title") %> 
    </h2>
    <div class="banner-desc">
       <p>
         <span> <%= I18n.t("features.text") %> </span>
       </p>
    </div>          
</div>
```

Comment: I am not sure if you are asking how to represent markdown in a YAML file and/or if you want to know how to get what you have inserted in the `.erb` (I can help with the former, not with the latter).

Comment: I don't know the correct format to represent the markdown in a YAML file.
I'm new to this(markdown). I don't how to implement the markdown and get the implemented value.

Answer (score 1):

For the part of the representation of [markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) in YAML, you can follow what I have been doing for [reStructuredText](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReStructuredText) (which is similar in concept, but which I prefer to use).

Line breaks and formatting are often significant in such text, so anything that you don't analyse and split up in keyword/value pairs you should put into YAML as a literal scalar (using `|`:

```
text: |
    Paragraphs are separated
    by a blank line.

    Leave 2 spaces at the end of a line to do a  
    line break
title: blahblah
```

and since you will have multiple titles and you shouldn't reuse a key in a YAML mapping, you should make the top structure into a list of flow (not block) style YAML.

That way you can walk over the list take the key value directly to decide what action to take (instead of having to parse the key with `title`, `title1`). But **most importantly key/value pairs in YAML mappings are not ordered and your parser probably does away with the ordering when reading the value of `features`**):

```
features:
  - title: 14 Chapters
  - text: |
      The book's main chapters take you through building a 
      **social news site**.
  - image: files.svg
  - title: 11 Sidebars
  - text: |
      In between each chapter, sidebars explain a specific aspect of Meteor.
  - image: files.svg
```

You don't have to quote string scalars, unless there might be confusion about their type (numbers, dates etc).